# MySQL: Returning More than 1 Row When Referencing Through Several Tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list all of the stores that sell products that contain specific guitar parts for a guitar rig.

I have a `guitarRig` database. Guitar rigs have `parts` (I.e. `amplifier`, `cabinet`, `microphone`, `guitarType`, `guitarStringType`, `patchCord`, `effectsPedal`) which come from products, which are purchased from stores.
Products are purchased for a price as dictated by my `PurchaseInformation` table.

Here are my tables:

```
Table Part:
    name
    guitarRig references GuitarRig(name)
    product references Product(name)

Table Product:
    name
    part references Part(name)
    barcodeNumber

Table PurchaseInformation:
    price
    product references Product(name)    
    purchasedFrom references Store(name)  
Table Store:
    name
    storeLocation
```

---

So far what I have is this:

```
SELECT p.name AS Part, prod.name AS Product, sto.name AS Store
FROM Part p, ProductInformation prod, Store sto, PurchaseInfo purch
WHERE   sto.storeNumber = purch.storeNumber
    AND purch.product = prod.name
    AND prod.Part = p.name
    AND p.name = 
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM Part
        WHERE name LIKE '%shielded%'
    )   
GROUP BY p.name;
```

The error I get is that it returns more than 1 row, however, this is what I want! I want to list the stores that sell products that contain the part I am searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to replace the equality comparison operator ( `=` ) with the `IN` operator.

```
    AND p.name IN 
    (
       SELECT name ...
```

---

I say that's the quick fix, because that will fix the error, but this isn't the most efficient way to write the query. And it's not clear your query is going return the result set you specified or actually expect.

I strongly recommend you avoid the old-school comma join operator, and use the JOIN keyword instead.

Re-structuring your query into an equivalent query yields this:

```
SELECT p.name AS Part
     , prod.name AS Product
     , sto.name AS Store
  FROM Part p
  JOIN ProductInformation prod
    ON prod.Part = p.name
  JOIN PurchaseInfo purch
    ON purch.product = prod.name
  JOIN Store sto
    ON sto.storeNumber = purch.storeNumber
 WHERE p.name IN
       (
         SELECT name
           FROM Part
          WHERE name LIKE '%shielded%'
       )
 GROUP BY p.name;
```

Some notes.  The `GROUP BY` clause is going to collapse all of the joined rows into a single row for each distinct part name. That is, you are only going to get one row back for each part name.

It doesn't sound like that's what you want. I recommend you remove that GROUP BY, and add an ORDER BY, at least until you figure out what resultset you are getting, and if that's the rows you want to return.

Secondly, using the `IN (subquery)` isn't the most efficient approach. If p.name matches a value returned by that subquery, since `p` is a reference to the same `Part` table, this:

```
 WHERE p.name IN
       (
         SELECT name
           FROM Part
          WHERE name LIKE '%shielded%'
       )
```

is really just a more complicated way of saying this:

```
 WHERE p.name LIKE '%shielded%'
```

---

I think you really want something more like this:

```
SELECT p.name     AS Part
     , prod.name  AS Product
     , sto.name   AS Store
  FROM Part p
  JOIN ProductInformation prod
    ON prod.Part = p.name
  JOIN PurchaseInfo purch
    ON purch.product = prod.name
  JOIN Store sto
    ON sto.storeNumber = purch.storeNumber
 WHERE p.name LIKE '%shielded%'
 ORDER BY p.name, prod.name, sto.name
```

That's going to return all rows from `Part` that include the string 'shielded' somewhere in the name.

We're going to match those rows to all rows in `ProductInformation` that match that part. (Note that with the inner join, if a `Part` doesn't have at least one matching row in `ProductInformation`, that row from `Part` will not be returned. It will only return rows that find at least one "matching" row in `ProductionInformation`.

Similarly, we join to matching rows in PurchaseInfo, and then to Store. Again, if there's not matching row from at least one `Store`, we won't get those rows back. This query is only going to return rows for `Parts` that are related to at least on `Store`. We won't get back any `Part` that's not in a `Store`.

The rows can be returned in any order, so to make the result set deterministic, we can add an ORDER BY clause. It's not required, it doesn't influence the rows returned, it only affects the sequence the rows that get returned.